# client-side problem with gridview in webpart ? arrg

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint

I have a webpart with a gridview.  The gridview has a command field
labeled 'select' - when clicked a value is passed to another webpart.
Works fine on several machines, but not on my bosses machine.  Could some IE8
setting or something else client-side be causing the problem?

Comment: Check the IE compatibility mode of the browser, more than likely a js error.

Answer (score 0):

Very likely to be client-side.  I'll hazard a guess that either:

- your boss doesn't have javascript enabled
- a javascript error is occuring
- your boss's machine can't access that second web part (is it local?)

Have you tried other browsers on your boss's machine?

Comment: I'll try another browser on boss's machine and see.  Didn't think turning javascript off was possible in IE8 (don't see the option under tools/internet otions/advance).

Comment: Yea it's possible - might also be javascript error so check for that

Comment: - ok - how do you disable javascript in IE?

Comment: Tools -> Security -> Custom Level